# Hide .desktop files from shares in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, samba, share

I share my desktop with VirtualBox. It allows me to work on current files in a nice easy way. I have quite a few utility launchers on my desktop. It's only a dozen or so at peak time but it makes navigating the list of real files a little harder when I'm working from Windows.

I was wondering if there was a way of excluding the files from the share. Either at VirtualBox (I've no idea where it keeps its samba configuration -- or if it actually uses samba at all for that matter) or in Windows.

Comment: Without a *decission* layer in betwean (e.g. samba) it's not possible. Linux files starting with a . (dot) at the beginning are also marked as hidden for Windows (VirtualBox). But for me you should move the Linux only desktop files to a different folder. My understanding is one desktop is one but not two with shared content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the VirtualBox documentation, it's clear that this isn't possible directly. But I have an idea which will work.

Using a Warren Falk's picfs fuse mount, you remount your Desktop under a hidden directory, say `.VirtualBox/shared/Desktop` and point virtual box at that. Then in the fuse mount configuration, you simply specify which files should be ignored.

See here for more details: http://www.warrenfalk.com/blog/2009/07/09/picsfs-fuse-filesystem/

Using this, your Desktop will be exactly the same to Linux, but your VirtualBox will see a controlled directory. The fuse code is even in python, so it's easy to modify. Let me know if you want instructions.

Comment: That's very cunning.